# Convert python uuid hashing code to php

Tags: php, python, sha

I'm trying to port large chunk of python code to php - while doing so I've found this one line which I can't find equivalent for:

```
    instance = resp.get(
        'instance',
        uuid.uuid4().hex.encode('utf-8')
    )

    sha = hashlib.sha1(
        self.username.encode('utf-8') + instance
    )
    self.params.update({'id': sha.hexdigest().upper()})
```

I've found https://github.com/ramsey/uuid to generate uuid4 and tried to mimic above like so:

```
    if (isset($resp['instance']))
    {
        $instance = $resp['instance'];
    }
    else
    {
        $uuid4 = Uuid::uuid4();
        $instance = utf8_encode(dechex($uuid4->toString()));
    }

    $sha = sha1(utf8_encode($this->username) . $instance);

    $this->params['id'] = strtoupper($sha);
```

This does not seem to provide same results. Can anyone help me out to produce same result in php as in python. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that dechex function is not the same as python's hex.
In this case result of hex function was removing dashes from uuid. Solved it with str_replace.